# How to use ffmpeg to capture a HLS/rtsp stream snapshot?

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to use ffmpeg to capture a HLS or RTSP stream snapshots.

Are there any simple way for me to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SO - I found the answer to this a while ago on stackexchange I think, so I'm just regurgitating info I found (ie; can't take credit!)

```
#!/bin/bash

# TimeLapse snapshot capture script.

# This script should capture any stills in the incoming Stills directory

time=`date '+%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S'`;

# Specific for each camera
CameraName=no-spaces-this-will-be-a-filename-eventually
CameraIP='192.168.1.150'

CameraUsername='user'
CameraPassword='password'

# Shouldn't need to be changed!
StorageDirectory=/mnt/storage/Stills
StorageFilename=$CameraName-$time.png

mkdir -p $StorageDirectory/$CameraName;

ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://$CameraUsername:$CameraPassword@$CameraIP:554/mainStream -ss 00:00:01.50 -vframes 1 $StorageDirectory/$CameraName/$StorageFilename -nostats -hide_banner -v 0 -loglevel quiet
```

Now - this works GREAT with HikVision cameras. Which is what I'm doing it with.

To break it down, the **-ss 00:00:01.50** means it streams a second and a half of footage THEN **-vframe 1** grabs 1 frame. This allows the stream to 'settle' so you don't end up with half an image.

I run this to do regular captures from cameras which I then, once a week, convert into a timelapse movie

```
#!/bin/bash

# TimeLapse footage creation script.

# This script should take any stills in the incoming Stills directory and
# compile them into a .mp4 file in the Movies directory.
# Then moved the 'processed' stills into a timestamped directory the
# Processed directory.

time=`date '+%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S'`;
source="/mnt/storage/"

for CameraName in `ls $source/Stills/`; do

# If the Movies directory for $CameraName doesn't exist, make it.
   mkdir -p /mnt/storage/Movies/$CameraName

# Make the movie in the Movie directory using the stills from the Stills directory
   ffmpeg -framerate 10/1 -pattern_type glob -i "$source/Stills/$CameraName/*.png" -vf fps=30 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p $source/Movies/$CameraName/$CameraName-$time.mp4

# Make the Processed directory for $CameraName if it doesn't already exist
   mkdir -p /mnt/storage/Processed/$CameraName
# Make the timestamped directory for the stills to be moved into
   mkdir -p /mnt/storage/Processed/$CameraName/$time
# Move the stills
   mv $source/Stills/$CameraName/*.png $source/Processed/$CameraName/$time/

done
```

The first script is on a cronjob to run every 5 mins.
The second script is on a cron job to run once a week.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Im gonna try ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://$CameraUsername:$CameraPassword@$CameraIP:554/mainStream -ss 00:00:01.50 -vframes 1 $StorageDirectory/$CameraName/$StorageFilename -nostats -hide_banner -v 0 -loglevel quiet
command here. As that is all I am asking here.

Comment: `-v 0` and `-loglevel quiet` are mutually exclusive (`-loglevel quiet` is the same as `-v -8`). Also, both commands imply `-nostats` and `-hide_banner`.